# delete[] messes up my program, what's happening

Tags: c++

I've looked at my program every way and I've tried everything yet I can't figure out why `delete[]` crashes my program.

header file

```
#ifndef SICT_PRODUCT_H
#define SICT_PRODUCT_H
#include "Streamable.h"
#include "general.h"

namespace sict{

class Product: public Streamable{
    char sku_[MAX_SKU_LEN+1];
    char* name_;
    double price_;
    bool taxed_;
    int quantity_;
    int qtyNeeded_;

public:
    Product();
    Product(const char* sku,const char* name, bool tax=true, double price=0,int needed=0);
    Product& operator=(Product &P);
    ~Product();
    void sku(char* sku);
    void price(double price);
    void name(char* name);
    void taxed(bool tax);
    void quantity(int q);
    void qtyNeeded(int n);
    const char* sku()const;
    double price()const;
    const char* name()const;
    bool taxed()const;
    int quantity()const;
    int qtyNeeded()const;
    bool isEmpty()const;
    bool operator==(const char* name);
    int operator+=(int num);
    int operator-=(int num);
    double cost()const;
};

double operator+=(double& num,const Product& P);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Product& P);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Product& P);

}

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Product.h"
using namespace std;

namespace sict{

Product::Product(){
    sku_[0]=0;
    name_=nullptr;
    price_=0;
    taxed_=0;
    quantity_=0;
    qtyNeeded_=0;
}

Product::Product(const char* sku,const char* name, bool tax, double price, int needed){
    strncpy(sku_, sku, strlen(sku) + 1);
    sku_[strlen(sku) + 1] = 0;
    if (name != nullptr || name != 0){
        delete[] name_;
        name_ = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(name_, name);
    }
    quantity_=0;
    taxed_=tax;
    price_=price;
    qtyNeeded_=needed;
}

Product& Product::operator=(Product &P){
    strncpy(sku_, P.sku_, strlen(P.sku_) + 1);
    sku_[strlen(P.sku_) + 1] = 0;
    delete[] name_;
    name_ = new char[strlen(P.name_) + 1];
    strcpy(name_, P.name_);
    taxed_ = P.taxed_;
    price_ = P.price_;
    qtyNeeded_ = P.qtyNeeded_;
    quantity_=P.quantity_;
    return *this;
}

Product::~Product(){
    delete[] name_;
    name_=nullptr;
}

void Product::sku(char* sku){
    strncpy(sku_,sku,strlen(sku)+1);
    sku_[strlen(sku)+1]=0;
}

void Product::price(double price){
    price_=price;
}

void Product::name(char* name){
    delete[] name_;
    name_= new char[strlen(name)+1];
    strcpy(name_,name);
}

void Product::taxed(bool tax){
    taxed_=tax;
}

void Product::quantity(int q){
    quantity_=q;
}

void Product::qtyNeeded(int n){
    qtyNeeded_=n;
}

const char* Product::sku()const{
    return sku_;
}

const char* Product::name()const{
    return name_;
}

bool Product::taxed()const{
    return taxed_;
}

int Product::quantity()const{
    return quantity_;
}

int Product::qtyNeeded()const{
    return qtyNeeded_;
}

double Product::price()const{
    return price_;
}

bool Product::isEmpty()const{
    if(sku_==0 && sku_[0]==0 && name_==nullptr && price_==0&&taxed_==0 && quantity_==0&& qtyNeeded_==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Product::operator==(const char* name){
    for(int i=0;name_[i]!=0;i++){
        if(name_[i]!=name[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int Product::operator+=(int num){
    return (num+quantity_);
}

int Product::operator-=(int num){
    return (quantity_-num);
}

double Product::cost()const{
    if (taxed_){
        return price_;
    }
    else
        return price_;
}

double operator+=(double& num, const Product& P){
    return (num+=(P.price()*P.quantity()));
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Product& P){
    P.write(os,P.taxed());
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Product& P){
    P.read(is);
    return is;
}
```

}

and finally the "main" file

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Product.h"

#ifdef TAB
# undef TAB
#endif

#define TAB '\t'

using namespace std;

namespace sict{

class SItem :public Product{

public:
    SItem(const char* theSku, const char * theName):Product(theSku, theName){}

    SItem(){}

    virtual std::fstream& store(std::fstream& file, bool addNewLine = true)const{
            if (!isEmpty()){
            file.open("ms4.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
            file << sku() << TAB << name() << TAB << quantity() << TAB << qtyNeeded() << TAB << int(taxed()) << TAB << price() << endl;
            file.clear();
            file.close();
        }
        return file;
    }

    virtual std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file){
        file.open("ms4.txt", ios::in);
        char buf[2000];
        double dbuf;
        int ibuf;
        file >> buf;
        sku(buf);
        file >> buf;
        name(buf);
        file >> ibuf;
        quantity(ibuf);
        file >> ibuf;
        qtyNeeded(ibuf);
        file >> ibuf;
        taxed(bool(ibuf));
        file >> dbuf;
        price(dbuf);
        file.clear();
        file.close();
        return file;
    }

    virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, bool linear)const{
        return isEmpty() ? os : (os << sku() << ": " << name() << ", qty: " << quantity() << ", qtyNeeded:" << qtyNeeded() <<", Cost: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << cost());
    }

    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is){
        char buf[2000];
        double dbuf;
        int ibuf;
        cout << "Sku: ";
        is >> buf;
        sku(buf);
        cout << "Name (no spaces): ";
        is >> buf;
        name(buf);
        cout << "Qty: ";
        is >> ibuf;
        quantity(ibuf);
        cout << "Qty Needed: ";
        is >> ibuf;
        qtyNeeded(ibuf);
        cout << "Is taxed? (1/0): ";
        is >> ibuf;
        taxed(bool(ibuf));
        cout << "Price: ";
        is >> dbuf;
        price(dbuf);
        return is;
    }
};

}

void dumpFile(fstream& f){
    f.open("ms4.txt", ios::in);
    char ch;
    while (!f.get(ch).fail()){
        cout.put(ch);
    }
    f.clear();
    f.close();
    }

using namespace sict;

void test(){
    double res, val = 0.0;
    fstream F("ms4.txt", ios::out);
    F.close();
    SItem S;
    SItem T;
    SItem U;
    cout << "Enter Product info: " << endl;
    cin >> S;
    SItem V = S;
    S.store(F);
    T.load(F);
    cout << "T: (store, load)" << endl;
    cout << T << endl;
    cout << "S: " << endl;
    cout << S << endl;
    cout << "V(S): " << endl;
    cout << V << endl;
    cout << "U=T & op= :" << endl;
    U = T;
    cout << U << endl;
    cout << "Operator == :" << endl;
    cout << "op== is " << (T == "1234" ? "OK" : "NOT OK") << endl;
    cout << "op+=: " << endl;
    U += 10;
    cout << U << endl;
    cout << "op+=double : " << endl;
    res = val += U;
    cout << res << "=" << val <<endl;
}

int main(){
    fstream F("ms4.txt", ios::out);
    F.close();
    SItem S;
    SItem U("4321", "Rice");
    cout << "Empty Prouduct:" << endl << S << endl;
    cout << "U(\"4321\", \"Rice\"):" << endl << U << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the following information:" << endl;
    cout << "Sku: 1234" << endl;
    cout << "Name(no spaces) : Blanket" << endl;
    cout << "Qty : 12" << endl;
    cout << "Qty Needed : 23" << endl;
    cout << "Is taxed ? (1 / 0) : 1" << endl;
    cout << "Price : 12.34" << endl;
    test();
    cout << "Please enter the following information:" << endl;
    cout << "Sku: 1234" << endl;
    cout << "Name(no spaces) : Jacket" << endl;
    cout << "Qty : 12" << endl;
    cout << "Qty Needed : 23" << endl;
    cout << "Is taxed ? (1 / 0) : 0" << endl;
    cout << "Price : 12.34" << endl;
    test();
    dumpFile(F);
    cout << "----The End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The general and streamable files if anyone is interested:

```
#ifndef SICT_GENERAL_H__
#define SICT_GENERAL_H__
#define TAX (0.13)          
#define MAX_SKU_LEN (7)      
#define DISPLAY_LINES (10)     
#define MIN_YEAR (2000)        
#define MAX_YEAR (2030)
#define MAX_NO_RECS (2000)
#endif



#ifndef SICT__Streamable_H_
#define SICT__Streamable_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
namespace sict{
class Streamable{
public:
virtual fstream& store(fstream& file, bool addNewLine = true)const =0;
virtual fstream& load(std::fstream& file)=0;
virtual ostream& write(ostream& os, bool linear)const=0;
virtual istream& read(istream& is)=0;
};
}
#endif
```

The program crashes at the very first `delete` statement, it does not even make it to the copy constructor. I've tried everything and I don't understand why it breaks at `delete[]`.

Comment: Can you please include the output of your crash? If it just says "Segmentation fault", run it through GDB and tell us what it says.

Comment: `strncpy(sku_, P.sku_, strlen(P.sku_) + 1);    sku_[strlen(P.sku_) + 1] = 0;` should be `strcpy(sku_, P.sku_);`

Comment: please use smart pointer. in this case, `unique_ptr`

Comment: in the `Product` constructor with `name` you `delete[] name_;` without initialising `name_`